# Looking to backup my laptop hdd with clonezilla but concerned about data loss

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, backup, clonezilla

I have an external HDD with 2 partitions, with one having more than enough space for cloning. if I clone the main partition, will it successfully transfer to the new partition or will the whole external harddrive be deleted and overwritten? i came across and warning and it confused me, so i just want to double check

Comment: DD can create an image of another partition on any partition you choose.  If you accidentally, restore an image to the wrong partition, then data loss is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clonezilla is a powerful tool, and it can be complex.  It should be possible to clone one partition into an image and store that image on a larger partition on the same drive, if you choose the correct options.

The Clonezilla web page has an example that is very close to your case.  You would just change step 9 so that you choose "saveparts" instead of "savedisk", and choose the correct source partition.  The documentation is here:

https://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/01_Save_disk_image

I have found Clonezilla to be relatively good about helping me avoid mistakes, but it is a bit complex, and it is powerful, so you should be careful when using it.  I would suggest taking a backup using a method you are already comfortable with before getting started, just to be careful.

Comment: what would be the main benefit to backing up a partition as an image via cloning?

Comment: A restored image is exactly identical (all of the timestamps, permissions, etc.) to the original.  Image style backups aren't as good at partial backups (images tend to result in larger backup sizes for incremental backups) or restores (a little harder to do partial restores), but they are typically a lot simpler to execute (the backup software is simpler and thus may be more reliable).  What made you look at Clonezilla, and what other options have you considered?

Comment: Well I first came across it looking to migrate a small 70gb to a bigger 750gb many years back but I think the software I used for that was possibly  from easus and not clonezilla. The first thing I thought of was clonezilla ths time because I thought that was what I used initially.  I just wanted a decent way to backup my drive before I tried to refresh or do anything else.